# Reload Solr configuration without multicore

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to [reload Solr configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD) without setting up Multicore or restarting the servlet container?

I would like to tweak some <analyzer> chains with the analysis tab in the admin, and tweak the parameters to my <requestHandler>, but having to restart the servlet container after every small change to schema.xml or solrconfig.xml is a bit of a pain and time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best as I can tell, online reloading requires a Multicore configuration, which it turns out isn't too hard:

Put this `solr.xml` into the solr home directory

```
<solr persistent="false" sharedLib="lib">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="core0">
    <core name="core0" instanceDir="." />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

Restart the servlet container.

Hit a URL like this to reload the configuration:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0
```

To remove the rest of the friction, you can set it up to automatically reload the configuration by running the following script within the `conf` directory.

```
get_on_fsevent.rb "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core0"
```

get_on_fsevent.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'rb-fsevent'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse(ARGV.first)

fsevent = FSEvent.new
fsevent.watch Dir.pwd do |directories|
  puts "Detected change. Requesting #{ARGV.first}"
  puts Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
end
fsevent.run
```

Answer (score 3):

There is always a core in SOLR. By default, SOLR instance creates a core named **collection1**. In case you have a single core and not sure how to reload at runtime, you can use this,

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=collection1
```

Comment: If you want to see various commands available to administer SOLR Cores, Check this blog post on [SOLR Commands](http://www.installationpage.com/solr/solr-admin-core-commands/).